# Systems of matrices

Tags: matrices, finite-fields

Consider an equation of the form AX=A where A is $m \times n$  $m<n$ matrix and X is an unknown $n \times n$ invertible matrix all matrices are over $\mathbb{F}_2$.

Can one characterize A when is there a non-identity solution to X and when $X=I_n$ is the only solution?

Comment: $X = I$ is the only solution if and only if $A$ has full column-rank.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom So for m<n there's always non-identity X? Since rank can be at most m.

Comment: Yes that is correct

Comment: @Omnomnomnom What if it's over some binary polynomial ring and not over $\mathbb{F}_2$? That is entries in X,A are from some $\mathbb{F}_2[x] / (x^t+1)$

Comment: In that case I'm not sure. If you're interested, I'd recommend that you post a new question about that with the abstract algebra tag

Comment: For the case of $t=2$, $A=(t+1)I$ is an example where the solution is not unique even though A apparently had "full column rank" in some sense.

Comment: I suspect that it suffices to check whether $\det(A^TA) $ is a unit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I have stated in a comment above, $X = I$ will be the only solution if and only if $A$ has full column-rank.

Because $\Bbb F_2$ is a field, the standard linear algebraic approaches apply.

Note that $AX = A$ if and only if $A(X - I) = 0$, and $A(X - I) = 0$ if and only if the column space of $X - I$ is contained in the null space of $A$.  If this only occurs when $X - I = 0$, then the null space of $A$ is trivial, which is to say that $A$ has full column-rank.